# Check Space in String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check that if my username contains space so then it alert so i do this it work but one problem i am facing is that if i give space in start then it does not alert.I search it but can't find solution, my code is this

```
var username    =   $.trim($('#r_uname').val());
var space = " ";
  var check = function(string){
   for(i = 0; i < space.length;i++){
     if(string.indexOf(space[i]) > -1){
         return true
      }
   }
   return false;
  }

  if(check(username) == true)
  {
     alert('Username contains illegal characters or Space!');
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Also, you're trimming the string, so how could there be a space at the beginning of it?

Comment: I use trim bt in db it dont remove space

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that you want to find out if a string has a space at the beginning of it, but you're trimming that space off before you check. So the solution would be to not trim the string...

Comment: @Nathan Bouscal you was right.thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `.indexOf()`:

```
var check = function(string) {
    return string.indexOf(' ') === -1;
};
```

You could also use regex to restrict the username to a particular format:

```
var check = function(string) {
    return /^[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(string)
};
```

Comment: indexOf would be the fastest method (versus regex to check for a space), however whitelisting what they CAN use via regex is probably safer than blacklisting what they cannot.

Comment: @Blender i use first method but it works in first case example if i give this string then it does not work ` space  abc def`

Comment: @AzamAlvi: Change `===` to `!==`.

Comment: @Blender does not work, open this jsfidle link http://jsfiddle.net/azamalvi/Lsg45/1/

Comment: @AzamAlvi: Works just fine for me. Try getting rid of `$.trim()`, as you're probably adding spaces to the beginning/end to test it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a regular expression to check for a whitespace character with `\s`:

```
if (username.match(/\s/g)){
    alert('There is a space!');
}
```

See the code in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vzZf/1/).

Comment: it's same as my function does. no alrt if space is given in start

Comment: check out the link to the jsFiddle I posted, it works as expected.

Comment: I think you should read up on `trim()` - it removes the spaces from the beginning and ending of a string, so when you use `var username = $.trim($('#username').val());` the space is removed from the field before you check it.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use something like this?

```
if(string.indexOf(space) > -1){
     return true
  }
```